# Cannot find module 'warnOnce'

Tags: react-native, babel-loader

When i upgrade my react-native version to 0.59.5 and i run webpack to create a bundle for my web app in the same folder app i get this error

```
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'warnOnce'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
  (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
```

I can't understand where is used this WarnOnce and how can i fix it ? Does someone face the same issue ? I did a cache clean and it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `resolver` in `module.exports` in your `metro.config.js` and make sure it looks something like below.

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
      /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
    ])
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```